# New Android 'hello, world' projects does not pass standard Lint test

Tags: android, eclipse, setup-project

I'm trying Android development under Archlinux with Eclipse Kepler SR2 from standard Arch repository. I use ru_RU.UTF8 locale.

I meet that basic 'Hello, World!" don't pass lint test. Is it okay?

I'm not sure it is a good idea to ignore it for newbies, because it looks like it is the only tool helps validating code on android-specific mistakes beyond of java translator.

So... What should i do? a) Fix that errors and continue, b) Switch that warnings in lint settings of project or c) ignore at all lint validator.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: `don't pass lint test. Is it okay?`  Have you considered telling us what the lint warnings are?

Comment: I don't know how to copy lint output from eclipse lint warnings window. It has 7 errors and 75 warnings... Errors are:

Comment: 1) 'app_name' is not translated in <list of locales> (3 instances)
2) This class should be public (android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.HomeView) 
3) Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix (2 instances)
4) Wrong orientation? No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal, yet this layout has multiple children where at least one has layout_width="match_parent"
Last two ones is under responsibility of appcompat_v7_5...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the ssame issue. I quit Eclipse and relaunched it.  Then Under the project menu I selected "clean" and "clean all projects".  After that just chose plain old run and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Lint should not be used in this stage. The problem are solved easy by removing all messages in Lint warnings window and running application in standard way. Sample code of "Hello World!" provided by Android SDK is not valid code from LINT PoV. it is just a minimal piece of code required for working application.